# Why wont video start downloading in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nginx, video, vps

MVC has a download link for every video:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameOfVideo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new {fileName = item.NameOfVideo})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Index function looks like this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(("./wwwroot/Videos/"));
    
    List<Video> files = filePaths.Select(filePath => new Video {NameOfVideo = Path.GetFileName(filePath)}).ToList();

    return View(files);
}
```

All my videos are stored in folder called Videos that is in wwwroot folder.

And this is download function:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string filename)
{
    // Get path with included filename
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Videos", filename);
    
    byte[]? file = null;
    FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
    file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    
    // GetContentType returns corresponding Mimetype
    return File(file, GetContentType(path), filename);
}
```

When I run it locally everything works, I can download any size and type videos.
When I upload the release build on my VPS(CentOs 8) and run it there, I noticed that I can still download files that are really small in size like 5000 bytes.
When I try downloading a bigger file in size than it just says "failed - file incomplete":

[image]

Is there somewhere a limit that limits max file size for download?
Also is the code for "DownloadFile" function optimal way for this type of application. I am trying to make really simple video database for my personal use and just to practice, max video size would stay around 1gb.

**Update 1**:
I did some additional troubleshooting and found out some interesting things.
I first created couple files with

```
fsutil file createnew <nameIsFileSizeInBytes> <length>
```

For example:

```
fsutil file createnew 500000 500000
```

That creates file named 500000 with size of 500000 Bytes.
Than I uploaded those files to release build on VPS and results were:
File with 200000 Bytes - downloadable
File with 250000 Bytes - NOT downloadable
File with 300000 Bytes - downloadable
File with 350000 Bytes - NOT downloadable
....
So pattern is pretty obvious here. This went up to 500000 Bytes file size, after that all downloads failed. So 500000 Bytes seems to be the max that can be downloaded. To further clarify I added video of downloading files:[video of download process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49YJF.gif)(Might need to zoom in to see :D)
Could anybody point me in right direction where should I look for the root of this weird problem(I am able to download large files from VPS and upload them via ftp)?

**Update 2**:
Did some troubleshooting via network tab(chrome), attached pictures of results:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ1CT.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyFWp.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx4tH.jpg)

Also I use nginx and maybe there is something in config that keeps me from downloading files?
[Config file of nginx](https://pastebin.pl/view/a38202c1)

Comment: You don't need to load all of the file into `file` like that - that is going to take RAM unnecessarily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_

Answer (score 1):

There is a default [limit of 30MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestbodysize?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for a request body size but I don't know any limit to a response body size in ASP.NET Core MVC. Maybe you should check web server configuration.

As for the code there is [`PhysicalFile` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.physicalfile?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_PhysicalFile_System_String_System_String_) that takes an absolute path to the file. No need to load the entire contents of the file into memory.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Download(string videoName)
    {
        var videoFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Join("wwwroot\\Videos", videoName));

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(videoFilePath))
            return NotFound();

        return PhysicalFile(videoFilePath, "application/octet-stream", videoName);
    }
```

Comment: Your code works nicely, and is way more effective, but I still have download problem, I updated my post with some more information to further describe the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using other tools to download files? Powershell has Invoke-WebRequest command. The progress circle looks weird in the video. As if the download stops and the browser tries to resume it (I'm just guessing). You can also check requests sent by the browser, press F12, reload the page, switch to network tab and start downloading.

Comment: Well I tried with network tab, and everytime no matter which file it was gave 200 result. I am having hard time trying to analyse the info from it. I added some pictures to my initial post, maybe you can make something out of them?